# Dj-stripe conflicts with multipe development severs

Tags: python, django

My team are developing a payment system for our web services. The site is built using Django, with the payment services provided by stripe. We are using dj-stripe to integrate the two.

For development we are using the stripe test environment, but we are doing this on multiple development servers, each with it's own dev DB.

dj-stripe identifies which customer to associate payment, card and source activity with using the dj-stripe customer id. This causes a conflict in the information for customers with the same ids on different development severs.

We have thought of a number of workarounds for this, the top two choices are;

1) Generate an offset in the customer ids to prevent clash. The issue is this may break down as time goes on, with more developers joining. It fixes the issue for now, but doesn't guarantee it won't be an issue again.

2) Create a stripe account for each developer to ensure no clashes and only use the test environment. However, this seems like something stripe wouldn't be happy with if we end up with many devs working on the project.

I am interested in whether there is a standard solution or best practices for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone comes here for a similar issue, Stripe responded very quickly to our question on this. They already have a feature to deal with this, it just wasn't immediately obvious to us.

Stripe have a feature for you to add multiple accounts from your dashboard. You can simple create an account for each developer and just use the test keys for that account. Then invite all developers in your team to have read access to the account so that everyone can see the logs.